# Выбор языка программирования, альтернативы C#

Tags: golang, c, d

Столкнулся с необходимостью иногда писать нативные программы.
 Решил изучить еще один язык программирования. Что нашел:
 C++ - точно не подходит. Вызывает только рвотный рефлекс (в своё время писал на нём, нынче избалован C#).
 D - собрат C++. Говорят красивее, но я пока не заметил. Особенно меня раздражает большое количество типов элементарных переменных (типа строки). А еще возникло ощущение что давно не обновлялся...
 Go - от гугла, пока еще не пробовал. Пытаюсь найти среду и компиляторы под Windows
 Vala - синтаксис C#. Но требует GTK+. Хотелось бы более или менее независимые программы получать. А GTK+ со всеми зависимостями весит 30Мб.
 FreeBasic - как-то несолидно :-). Да и что-то у меня трудности возникли...

У кого есть еще какие-нибудь предложения? Или дополнения по вышеуказанным языкам (кроме С и C++ - они точно меня не интересуют). Спасибо!

UPD: Эзотерика не интересует

UPD2: Вобще помощи от местного сообщества не дождаться. Большая часть ответов состоит либо из издёвок (не по теме), либо из ответов не подходящих под условия вопроса. Ожидал несколько большей компетенции от местной аудитории.
Некоторый ответы, правда позволили подчерпнуть что-то новое.
Решено изучить Vala, переписать программку, из-за которой всё задумано. Разрешить все зависимости и посмотреть сколько это будет весить.
Далее попробую Go, а за ним C++ + qt... Ну и в крайнем случае возьмусь за C...
Или даже за Forth :-)

Я ищу язык программирования (и среду) на котором мне будет комфортно программировать. При условии что в основном я пишу именно на C#.

Comment: Go точно не native. Если не секрет, чем C (без плюсов) не угодил ?

Comment: Почему Go не native?

Comment: Хм а что вы считаете эзотеричным? ЕМНИП OCaml умеет натив, всякие там лиспы и прочая маргинальщина умеет натив.

Comment: Собственно хочется спросить: "Вам шашечки или ехать?"

Comment: Эзотеричным я считаю языки вроде ниже предложенного лолкода...

Comment: Эх, тогда вам никогда не познать все прелести функционального программирования на brainfuck.

Comment: Вот больше всего боялся что мне брэйнфак предложат :-)

Comment: Если вы заметили то я вам его не предлагаю.

Comment: Я все больше склоняюсь к мнению что вы сюда потроллить зашли.

Comment: Ммм... В каком месте это похоже на троллинг?

Comment: В том где вы жалуетесь на избыточность всего и вся, а потом все же склоняетесь в сторону кутэ... >_<' АМ кагбе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если "для себя" - то рекомендую посмотреть:

1) Forth - для повышения общего образования.

2) Erlang - почти функциональный язык, главная фича - многопоточность (может держать сотни тысяч потоков), для недалёкого многоядерного будущего - самое то.

3) Java - и его функциональное продолжение - Scala.

Comment: Форт гляну, но потом. Почитал. Довольно интересный язык, но сейчас у меня несколько другая задача, нежели изучение принципиального нового языка (для меня).
Erlang - работает на виртуальной машине. Не подходит.
Java и Scala - работают на виртуальной машине. Не подходят.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, есть средства компиляции байт-кода Java в натив.

Comment: Честно - не хочу разбираться :-)
Ява изначально предназначалась для виртуальной машины, а значит компиляция просто откидывает большинство преимуществ...

Отмечаю ответ как правильный только за Forth :-)

Answer (score 5):

При выборе языка программирования всегда нужно учесть множество факторов, как минимум:

- наличие первоклассной цепочки инструментов (компиляторы, интерпретаторы, среды разработки),
- наличие необходимой документации,
- наличие библиотек готового кода,
- наличие на рынке достаточного количества специалистов, знакомых с языком,
- и т.д.

Сейчас для компилируемых программ используют в основном C++ и реже C (в зависимости от предметной области). D за все время своего существования, так и не стал промышленно используемым языком. А Go только начинает свое развитие. Поэтому особого выбора в общем-то и нет.

Лично для себя (как хобби) можно выбрать любой язык по вкусу, а для работы либо С, либо C++, и возможно в будущем Go.

Comment: Ну для работы у меня и есть C#... Я себе для хобби скорее подбираю.
Пока присматриваюсь к Go. )

Answer (score 4):

Из всего выше прочитанного я понял что вас от всего воротит и со всем давние счеты.

Зачем спрашивать было? lolcode вам в помощь.
[lolcode.com](http://lolcode.com/)

Comment: Воротит только от C++. Дельфи как и паскаль мне просто еще с первого курса не нравятся (есть причины).
С - просто пока не рассматривал, но если больше ничего не подойдет, попробую его погрызть)
С остальными названными знаком только поверхностно, потому и прошу совета.
Эзотерику не надо только предлогать...

Comment: Си грызть не надо. 

Он прост как две палки и веревка. Можно даже функции libc не использовать, просто на системных вызовах (+ native .dll). Вообще его можно рассматривать, как макроассемблер с типами.  
Тем и хорош !

Comment: Проблема не сколько в сложности, сколько в том, что я уже достаточно сильно избалован си-шарпом :-)

Answer (score 3):

Если от плюсов воротит, тогда может Delphi? У нее и у C# один автор и идеи близкие (для меня - шарп - это одна с веток развития Delphi-C++Builder'a).

Comment: Не нравится мне Delphi... У нас с ним давние счеты)))

Comment: Ну тогда только ассемблер или писать свой язык программирования. Все остальное либо экзотика, либо не нативное (Питон, Жава)

Comment: Ассемблер точно не подходит... Для прикладных задач он не подходит...

Answer (score 3):

То лишнее, это весит много, от того рвет... А Вас не смущает что некоторые наглые языки компилятор требуют?..

Пишите bat-скрипты, запустятся на голой XP, зависимостей нет, не нужно ужасной ГТК+ на 30 метров (а сколько дотНЕТ весит?) - и будет Вам счастье!

Comment: 4й дотнет, если мне память не изменяет весит 30-40 мб...
да и прична выбора нативного языка как раз была в том, чтобы отказаться от зависимостей... 
хотел бы я посмотреть как вы гуи будете через бат-скрипты делать...
вобщем ответ без ответа...

Comment: хотел бы я посмотреть на язык который попадет под все ваши требования. С/С++ и WinAPI - вот единственное что не требует каких-то особых зависимостей. Но вас же воротит...

Comment: .NET4 инсталлятор только весит мегабайт 70. А распаковывается в традиционные 700МБ. При этом .NET друг с другом несовместимы. Т.е. программа под .NET3.5 требует именно его, а не, скажем, 4.0.

Comment: Вот это точно бред. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718 - 48 Мб (и это дистрибутив для х86 и х64). Сколько занимает после установки не знаю (да и имеет ли это значение?), но папка весит 170 Мб.
Да, раньше были проблемы с запуском различных версий фреймворка, но в большинстве случаев это было вызвано кривыми руками программистов.
Сейчас же достаточно установки версии 4.0 (как сделано у меня на рабочем компьютере) для запуска программ .NET предназначенных для любой версии фреймворка. Разберитесь в вопросе, прежде чем давать настолько некомпетентные комментарии...

Comment: @1101_debian: у WinAPI есть зависимость, называется "Windows" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> Что нашел: C++ - точно не подходит. Вызывает только рвотный рефлекс (в своё время писал на нём, нынче избалован C#).

Я тоже на нём писал. Сначала думал, что хороший язык. Когда увидел C#, захотел чего-то большего в C++, потому что C# мне не подходил по другим параметрам. Когда начал натыкаться на грабли с C++, пытаясь писать свой движок с интерфейсом в стиле C#, сначала боролся. Потом понял, что это пустая трата времени и сил, и возненавидел C++, обратив внимание именно на D.

> D - собрат C++.

Это язык, который взял всё лучшее от C#, Java и C++ и добавил ещё некоторые вещи.

> Говорят красивее, но я пока не заметил.

А я сразу заметил. Наверное у тебя не достаточно опыта, чтобы заметить разницу.

> Особенно меня раздражает большое количество типов элементарных переменных (типа строки).

Строки в D - это частный случай массивов, а в твоём C# строки - это как раз отдельный тип.

> А еще возникло ощущение что давно не обновлялся.

Новая версия компилятора выходит каждый месяц, если не чаще. Ты наверно зашёл на какой-нибудь русский заброшенный сайт. Надо смотреть на официальный сайт.

> Решено изучить Vala

Я тоже на неё обратил внимание, но когда увидел, что там нет перегрузки функций, понял, что не вариант.

В общем, рекомендую всё-таки обратить внимание на D. Правда, нужно знать английский, потому что почти вся информация написана на нём.

Извините за некропостинг, да ещё и в закрытую тему. Просто не удержался.

Comment: Ди -- отстой. Две разных версии языка, две разныз стандартных библиотеки, намешано дофига разных фич в лучших традициях C++.

Comment: Про первую версию забудь - она уже не актуальна. Вместе с ней осталась в прошлом библиотека Tango. Её конечно портировали на D2, но там она никому не нужна, и уже её не назовёшь стандартной.

 То что сильно упрощает жизнь, часто в C++ реализовывается жуткими костылями и работает не всегда (а это только её усложняет!). В D сделано либо уже изначально, либо есть нормальные средства для реализации всего, что угодно, работающего так, как будто встроено в язык.

Comment: Например, свойства в C++ реализуются через перегрузку операторов. Если даже смириться с тем, что при этом размер объектов увеличится, то всё равно при появлении auto и declspec из нового стандарта, тип будет определяться самого свойства, а не переменной. Вот за такие дела я и невзлюбил C++. А ведь он задумывался именно таким, на котором можно реализовать всё что угодно, но на деле в нём куча специализированных функций и мало универсальных. То же самое и в C#, но там хотя бы всё почище. А вот в D нужной мне универсальности выше крыши.

Comment: Он почище, но всё равно, слишком сложный язык, не соблюдается ортогональность фич.

Я какое-то время смотрел на D как на заменитель C++, но потом изменил своё мнение в пользу Go.

ЗЫ: Считаю что разрабы D клёво поимели сообщество, когда выпустили вторую версию языка. Кто-то делал на первой версии проекты, а разрабам захотелось ещё творчества.

Answer (score 1):

Бери Python, точно не прогадаешь.

Comment: Python - интерпретируемый язык. Рассматривал Cython но так и не понял что это :-)
Мне нужен язык - программы на котором компилируются в нативный код для windows без лишних зависимостей...

Comment: Если найду вариант пайтона, который подходит под условия - выберу его. Мне он нравится, к тому же я его немного знаю)

Comment: Хм натив без зависимостей под винду это ассемблер. А вообще накой такой изврат то надо если не секрет? И чтоб при этом ещо пайтон не справился.

Comment: Я написал же - без ЛИШНИХ зависимостей. Питон не справится, потому что для него на машине должен быть установлен интерпретатор.
А изврат нужен, для того чтобы переписать одну программку с C# так чтобы она запускалась на голой винде XP. Ну и на будущее для подобных задач...

Comment: Хм если руки прямые то спокойно собирается в бинарь и ставится на голую винду.
Притом эта программка вдруг начнет запускаться на всех мажорных ОС(ну только если там не виндо специфичный код внутри будет)

Comment: Ммм... Подскажите пожалуйста как его "собрать в бинарь". При этом не добавив зависимостей на Х метров или не раздув бинарик.
Буду очень благодарен, ибо пайтон мне очень симпатизирует...

Comment: @Scipetr: а как у компилируемого питона с функцией [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)?

Comment: >> так чтобы она запускалась на голой винде XP

Эээ... Зачем? На "голой винде ХР" вообще мало чего запустится, всякие C Runtime нужны. Ты ищешь проблему вместо того, чтобы ее решать.

Comment: @Flammable, обратите внимание, Вы пытаетесь бесседовать с человеком, который последний раз был здесь 23 Авг '11 4:29 (полтора года назад).

Comment: @avp, заметил после того, как написал :)